# How can I make draggable elements droppable instead of appending?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jquery-ui

I have a simple drag n drop it is working fine as I expected 
but,

**Problem:**

The only problem is the elements are appending

**What I want:**

I don't want to append the elements I just want that when I drag n drop the element
they appear as normally happen.

My Code:

```
$( "#editorDesignView" ).droppable({
        accept: '.textTemplate',
      drop: function( event, ui ) {
        var html = '<div id="" style="background: #eee; width: 80%; margin: 10px auto; padding: 10px;"><p contenteditable="true" style="padding: 5px;">'+ui.draggable.text()+'.</p></div>';        
  $(html).appendTo(this).hide().slideDown();
  }
    });
```

[Here is my fiddle.](https://jsfiddle.net/pL4Lv6r9/84/)

**UPDATE:**

I don't want to remove or want the same element as in left side. I just want that when I drop the element I can drop it anywhere

**UPDATED FIDDLE:**

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/MyTests/nmpgfyed/3/). Please check the console for the result. I want the result to be printed on droppable are without appending it.

Comment: What do you mean? You want to drop and remove from the left list?

Comment: @lonut No. I don't want to remove the elements from left list I want that when I drop the element I can drop it any where.

Answer (score 0):

you want a same representation on right column, as in left. And you can drop in anywhere at right column.

```
$(function(){

  $(".textTemplate").draggable({
    helper: "clone",
    zIndex: 2500,
  });
  $( "#editorDesignView" ).droppable({
        accept: '.textTemplate',
      drop: function( event, ui ) {
        console.log(ui.draggable.text(), event, ui);
        var html = '<div>'+ui.draggable.text()+'</div>';        
  $(html).appendTo(this).hide().slideDown();
  }
    });


});
```

Here is my [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/rhrhruw0/)

Comment: Thanks for the answer but sorry this was not my aim

Comment: I have added a new fiddle Please have a look